# Which CAS can do non-commutative differential algebra?

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, computer-algebra-systems, differential-algebra

I am looking for a CAS (possibly incl. additional packages/libraries) that can compute *generic* **non-commutative** differential expressions. Let me illustrate what I mean by two examples.

Let $(R,\partial)$ be a *generic* **non-commutative** differential ring (i.e. $\partial$ is a derivation on $R$), say of characteristic 0, and let $f \in R$ be a *generic* element. Then it should be able to express
$$
\partial^2(1+f)^2
$$
as
$$
2 \partial^2(f) + \partial^2(f) f + 2 \partial(f)^2 + f \partial^2(f)
$$
and
$$
(f\partial)^2 f
$$
as
$$
f \partial(f)^2 + f^2 \partial^2 (f)
$$
Note that *generically* the elements $f$ and $\partial(f)$ don't necessarily commute.

Comment: Just write your own codes.

Comment: The Weyl algebras, you mean? Apparently SageMath has a few related classes. (You don't have to install it, you can use [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)). Or if you indeed want *derivations* rather than the usual Leibniz's rule, there are univariate polynomial rings. However I'm not sure about generic elements.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist: no, not Weyl algebras, just a generic non-commutative ring equipped with a generic derivation. The point is that I need the output to be expressed in terms of $\partial$ and $f$ only, whereas the concreteness of Weyl algebras (imposed by the the relations between the generators $x_i$ and $\partial / \partial x_j$) will obscure that - it would be too concrete. What I am after, is actually simpler because $\partial^k(f)$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, are treated as blackboxes.

Comment: [This recent conference paper](http://gregensburger.com/AADIOS2023/ACA2023_abstract_jimenez.pdf) notes a few implementations of *related* things in other CAS and also advertises a WIP SageMath package that allows one to define a differential ring. I don't know whether it can represent "unevaluated" $\partial^k f$, maybe you can contact the author directly.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist: Nice find! This looks very promising (and even mentions corresponding packages for different CAS-es)! Thank you!

Comment: When you manage to find a working package for this task, please remember to write an answer here :-)